Cannot set ENV variable in azure pipeline with value from other step
So I am generating an access token from Databricks to test connection in CI/CD azure devops.
I am able to generate the token, i am able to echo it in another step (for testing purposes). But one step uses env: to list environment variables and I need to pass this token to the environment variable but that does not seem to work.
Here is that part of the pipeline.
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Generate Databricks credentials'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d").Token
      Write-Host "##vso\[task.setVariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN;isOutput=true;isSecret=false\]$token"
  name: GenerateTokenStep

- script: echo $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN) \<--- this works
  displayName: 'Echo Databricks token'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "dbt debug"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
    ScriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      echo "dbx token: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"
      dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location)
  env:
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
    DATABRICKS_HOSTNAME: $(DATABRICKS_HOSTNAME)
    DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH: $(DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH)
    DATABRICKS_SCHEMA: $(DATABRICKS_SCHEMA)
    DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN) \<--- this doesnt seem to work

Anyone has an idea why this is not working?
I tried changing the variable set line to this:
echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN;isOutput=true;isSecret=false]$token"

But this seems to have the same behaviour.

You are doing in correct way, the yaml works on my side.
Only removed extra \ when setting variables in AzurePowerShell@5 task based on your yaml:
pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Generate Databricks credentials'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn4'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d").Token
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN;isOutput=true;isSecret=false]$token"
  name: GenerateTokenStep

- script: echo $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN) #<--- this works
  displayName: 'Echo Databricks token'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "dbt debug"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn4'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "dbx token: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"
      echo "dbx token: $DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  env:
    DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN) 

To use the variable, you can use $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN), or read from env as $DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN as you set in last AzureCLI@2 task. Please check the doc Access variables through the environment.

It's recommended to copy my yaml for a test. I used Microsoft-hosted agent to avoid any local agent influence.

If you are using the variable in different job/stage,  please check the doc for the sample.

In short, you are setting an environment variable at the task level but are trying to access it as a pipeline variable.
Instead of using $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN) or $(DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN) in the script:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "dbt debug"
  inputs:
    # ...
    inlineScript: |
      echo "dbx token: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"
      dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location)
  env:
    # other variables bere
    DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)

Try ${DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN} (bash) or ${Env:DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN} (Powershell):
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "dbt debug"
  inputs:
    # ...
    inlineScript: |
      echo "dbx token: ${DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
      dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location)
  env:
    # other variables bere
    DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)

Full working example
Accessing pipeline variables in different steps, jobs or stages as per Set an output variable for use in the same job:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: A
    displayName: 'Stage A'
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: GenerateToken
        displayName: 'Generate token'
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - pwsh: |
              $token="password123456" #
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN;isOutput=true]$token"
            displayName: 'Set token'
            name: GenerateTokenStep
          - script: |
              echo "$(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"
            displayName: 'Echo token'
          - script: |
              echo "${DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
            displayName: 'Echo token using environment variable'
            env:
              DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
      - job: UseToken
        displayName: 'Use token'
        dependsOn: GenerateToken
        variables:
          - name: token
            value: $[ dependencies.GenerateToken.outputs['GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN'] ]
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Token: ${DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
            displayName: 'Echo token in bash script'
            env:
              DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(token)
          - pwsh: |
              Write-Host "Token: ${Env:DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
            displayName: 'Echo token in powershell script'
            env:
              DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(token)

  - stage: B
    displayName: 'Stage B'
    dependsOn: A
    jobs:
      - job: UseToken
        displayName: 'Use token'
        variables:
          - name: token
            value: $[ stageDependencies.A.GenerateToken.outputs['GenerateTokenStep.DATABRICKS_TOKEN'] ]
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Token: ${DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
            displayName: 'Echo token in bash script'
            env:
              DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(token)
          - pwsh: |
              Write-Host "Token: ${Env:DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
            displayName: 'Echo token in powershell script'
            env:
              DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(token)


Below sample will help you, simple and clear:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
# This step creates a new pipeline variable: doThing. This variable will be available to subsquent steps.
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing]Yes"
  displayName: Step set variable

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Value of doThing (as doThing): $(doThing)"
  displayName: Step --- print 1

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Value of doThing (as doThing): $env:DOTHING"
  displayName: Step --- print 2

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Value of doThing (as doThing): $env:DOTHING_ENV"
  env:
    DOTHING_ENV: $(doThing)
  displayName: Step --- print 3


